# Calculated column shows the value of another column, how in SP2013?

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have sharepoint 2013 portal. I have a list with some columns. Now I would like to add a new calculated column. In this column I would like to show the selected item in another column. This other column is a lookup to another list. It shows the Title in a dropdownbox. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution my self. I would like to share it with you. Go to the calculated column settings. There you can implement formula. On the right you can see the columns. Just double click on the column you would like to show in the calculated column.